# How to access predefined environment variables in conda environment.yml?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I wish to share an environment.yml file for others to reproduce the same setup as I have. The code we use depends on the environment variable $PWD. I wish to set a new env variable in the environment.yml where I can access $PWD.

for eg. I am able to do:

```
variables:
  VAR1: something
```

but can't do

```
variables:
      VAR1: $PWD/solution
```

where $PWD is set based on where the user has cloned the repo.

Also, how do I update predefined environment variables such as $PYTHONPATH?

```
variables:
    PYTHONPATH: $PWD:$PYTHONPATH
```

doesn't work similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Since the bash code used to set environmental variables is still built with `f"export {envvar}='{value}'" for envvar, value in sorted(env_vars.items())` in [initialize.py](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/main/conda/core/initialize.py), you can trick it into using an existing variable if you close and re-open the single quotes:

```bash
$ conda --version
conda 22.11.1
$ cat test.yaml
variables:
    VAR1: "'$PWD/solution'" # or "'$PWD'/solution"
$ conda env create -f test.yaml -p test_env
$ conda activate test_env/
(/my/working/directory/test_env) $ echo $VAR1
/my/working/directory/solution
```

AFAIK this is not documented and thus should not be relied upon
(and is also system-specific). In addition, this would not work if you want to use e.g. `$CONDA_PREFIX` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue while accessing gitlab variables within environment.yml. I didnt find any solution on internet and finally i had to follow below in my gitlab-ci.yml's script section:

- create conda environment using yml file
- activate environment
- create variables using `conda env config vars set VAR=value`
- deactivate environment
- activate environment

Comment: wow - that is really not possible? in 2022? I have been searching for "this" (using ENV VARs in yaml or more precisely .condarc) for about 2 hours now ... until I finally ran into this post - still hard to believe though that it cannot be achieved