# In the conda environment.yml file, how do I append to existing variables without overriding them?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

This is a follow up question for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62508395/1673784). For a conda environment specification file `environment.yml`, if the variable that I am defining is `PATH`, for example, how can I prepend or append to it instead of just overwriting it? Is the following correct?

```py
name: foo
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python
variables:
  MY_VAR: something
  OTHER_VAR: ohhhhya
  PATH: /some/path:$PATH
```

Comment: Hello, I am interested if anyone has the answer. As of yesterday, I used:  `MY_VAR: $(CONDA_PREFIX)` and it worked well, but I updated Conda and it doesn't work anymore.  Now running Conda 4.14.0

Comment: Another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69534089/how-to-access-predefined-environment-variables-in-conda-environment-yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It dependes on whether you are using windows or linux. A look at the [source code](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/6ea6a2d4d215d9118a1e10560c8931e97f6ebd4c/conda/core/initialize.py#L196) of the environment init code reveals that conda itself simply executes bash (linux) or cmd.exe (win) calls:

[linux](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/6ea6a2d4d215d9118a1e10560c8931e97f6ebd4c/conda/core/initialize.py#L218):

```py
yield from (f"export {envvar}='{value}'" for envvar, value in sorted(env_vars.items()))
```

[windows](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/6ea6a2d4d215d9118a1e10560c8931e97f6ebd4c/conda/core/initialize.py#L241):

```py
yield from (f'@SET "{envvar}={value}"' for envvar, value in sorted(env_vars.items()))
```

So make sure that you are using the correct syntax for your variable. In case of linux, that would be

```yaml
variables:
  MY_VAR: something
  OTHER_VAR: ohhhhya
  PATH: /some/path $PATH
```

AFAIK windows uses `;` to delimit entries, so you would probably have to do this (untested):

```yaml
variables:
  MY_VAR: something
  OTHER_VAR: ohhhhya
  PATH: /some/path;%PATH%
```

Comment: The quotes around `'{value}'` mean that variables, such as `$PATH` are not expanded. So the result of $PATH will be literally `/some/path $PATH`, and this will not work. (Besides, the delimiter of $PATH in linux is `:`, not a whitespace.) See also discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69534089/how-to-access-predefined-environment-variables-in-conda-environment-yml

Comment: @Luce Single quotes is not a reliable way of preventing expansion because you can close and re-open them, so the following hack would work: `PATH: "/some/path:'$PATH'"`. The problem is that e.g. `$CONDA_PREFIX` is not available at the time when the environment is being created.